# Place Marker at current position when function called javascript/google maps v3 api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am currently developing a web app that pulls your location through `html5`, then when a function is called, it places a marker at the current position, then you can add data to the marker. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

My code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SwiftAppDesign/ExVpQ/), the top and bottom are in `jquery.mobile`, thanks

Swift

Comment: Are you trying to display dynamic content in the info window? Or is it static content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manipulate the content that is going in to the google map infowindow you can actually set a variable for the content. If you look at the following code block for the info window

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          map: map,
          position: pos,
          content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
        });
```

If you notice the infowindow has a property called 'content'. If we wanted, we could modify that code block and make a viarible the content.

```
var infoContent = 'Content I want to be in the Infowindow';
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          map: map,
          position: pos,
          content: infoContent
        });
```

Now you can just assign whatever dynamic content you want to that variable and it will display in the infowindow.

Comment: also the question was how to place a info window at the current location when a function is triggered

Comment: So you're trying to display the window after you determine what the content is I presume?

Comment: not quite, the idea is when the function is triggered it finds your location, places an info window there, then gives you a window to set the info content in, e.g.: a text box and a button to submit the text to the variable

Comment: Okay, you could do that by asking the user to input content with a javascript prompt box, and then displaying that in the infowindow.

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/ExVpQ/1/

If you're actually looking for an input like html element that's possible too.

Working on an example for input/button combo

Comment: thanks, by input/button combo do you mean the prompt is button activated? cus thats what I'm after

Comment: Well as is, when you hit submit on the prompt window the content is set for the infowindow, what more are you trying to do with it?